# Passing accessToken from frontend to PHP API

Tags: laravel, auth0

I've been trying to get authentication working (described below) in my laravel application, following these two tutorials:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/laravel/01-login
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/laravel/01-authorization

On the frontend (angular app):

1. User clicks log in button and taken to auth0 login page
2. The user logs in and is redirected back to the callback with the accessToken
3. The access token is stored on the frontend and passed to Laravel API each request.

On the backend:

1. User makes a request to my http://localhost/api/route passing the accessToken in the authorisation header
2. Laravel validates the user is logged in and valid.
3. Laravel allows access to that route

It works to an extend, but when I try to use postman to access the protected route by passing the accessToken I get the error:

"message": "We can't trust on a token issued by: `https://myprojectname.au.auth0.com/`."

Is my workflow correct? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show you code?

Comment: Sounds like you need to approve your endpoint with auth0. The error you're seeing is a validation or security error from auth0.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if somebody facing with the same issue. The `authorized_iss` must contain a trailing slash.

In the laravel-auth0.php file the field,

```
'authorized_issuers' => 'https://myprojectname.au.auth0.com/'
```

should be in this form.